# Fscanf gets the values wrong

Tags: c, struct, scanf

I'm reading from an external file values but fscanf wont read it correctly

I have my information in an external .c file in the form [char float int\n char float int\n...]but for some reason using fscanf in a while loop as    fscanf(time, "%s %.2f %d\n", temp, tempp, temps); 
everything is saved in the temp variable so when i try to print it the results are

```
name: tetris, price: 0.00, sold: 0
name: 9.99, price: 0.00, sold: 0
```

the saved file looks like this

```
Tetris 9.99 4
Wormgame 4.50 5
```

my struct is

```c
    struct game {
        char *name;
        float price;
        int sold;
    };
```

function that reads

```c
    struct game * open_file(char * tiedosto) {
        char* filen = strcat(tiedosto, ".c");
        struct game *newarray = malloc(sizeof(struct game));
        newarray[0].name = NULL;
        FILE* time = fopen(tiedosto, "r");
        if (!time) {
            return NULL;
        }
        int characters = 0;
        int linechange = 0;
        while ((characters = fgetc(time)) != EOF) {
            if (characters == '\n') {
                linechange++;
            }
        }
        rewind(time);
        char temp[100];
        float tempp;
        int temps;
        int i;
        for ( i = 0; i < linechange; i++) {
            fscanf(time, "%s %.2f %d\n", &temp, &tempp, &temps); // this is where the problem lies 
            newarray = add_peli(newarray, temp, tempp);
            newarray[i].sold = temps;

        }
        fclose(time);
        print_items(newarray, i);
        return newarray;
    }
```

and lastly the function that adds the name to the struct

```c
    struct game *add_peli(struct game* array, char* nimi, float hinta )
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; array[i].name != NULL; i++) {
            if (array[i].name != NULL) {
                if (strcmp(array[i].name, nimi) == 0) {
                    printf("Game already exists\n");
                    return array;
                }
            }
        }
        struct game* newarray = realloc(array, sizeof(struct game) * (i + 2));

        newarray[i].name = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(nimi)+1));
        strcpy(newarray[i].name, nimi);
        newarray[i].price = hinta;
        newarray[i].sold = 0;
        newarray[i + 1].name = NULL;
        return newarray;
    }
```

as mentioned it for some reason just returns the right amount of games as in if I insert two games and then save the file it will only return two instances

Comment: One suggestion: *always* check the return value of `fscanf`.  One common problem is that an earlier call has failed, and the unparseable input has been left on the input, causing all later calls to fail, too.  If `fscanf` fails, and you ignore its return value telling you so, your variables (`temp`, `tempp`, `temps`) won't have been filled in with anything, but you won't realize it.

Comment: What happens if the last line doesn't end with a newline?

Comment: And if you already know the number of records (which is equal to the number of lines) then why allocate and reallocate? Just allocate *once*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude they should all end with newline as it is written to the .c file with fpritf("%s %f %d\n")

Comment: does it work with the format string `"%s %f %d\n"` instead of `"%s %.2f %d\n"` ?

Comment: Oh and almost *never* should you have a trailing white-space (like newline) in a `scanf` format string. It's almost always wrong. It's not the problem here, but please remove it.

Comment: Wow @SanderDeDycker that worked, I feel really stupid now...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'll change it, thanks!

Comment: If you want the intellectual satisfaction of solving this problem with `fscanf` (of which there are dozens), then by all means, proceed.  But, if you'd just like to read structured input from a file, reliably, and get on with your life, and never use the *scanf family again, then you can instead read whole lines with `fgets`, and break them into whitespace-separated "words" using `strtok` or the like, and convert the numeric ones using `strtol` and `strtod` (or `atoi` and `atof`), and be done with it.

Comment: As an alternative to the method described by @SteveSummit, you could read the lines with `fgets` (as he mentions) but then use `sscanf` to "parse" the input. At least this way it will be easier to handle lines with errors.

Comment: For the most part, you need to take *no action* with whitespace in the input when using the `scanf` function family. Most of the formats automatically filter out leading whitespace. Some exceptions are `%c` and `%[]` and `%n`.

Comment: And now that it's working, you might try it with the input line `chess 99.99 none` and see what happens...

Comment: The question has way too much code. In the end you would just have needed **one file** with **one** line in it and 5 lines to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Also trust me - it is better to not mix Finnish and English in variable names :D

Comment: `char* filen = strcat(tiedosto, ".c");` is suspect too - how array pointed to by `tiedosto` had suitably 2 extra characters for the suffix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `"%.2f"` is a valid format specifier for [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), it isn't for [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). Use `"%f"` instead, ie. :

```
fscanf(time, "%s %f %d\n", temp, &tempp, &temps);
```

Answer (score 0):

> fscanf(time, "%s %.2f %d\n", &temp, &tempp, &temps); // this is where the problem lies

First, lose the `&` operator on `&temp` - since it's an array, the *expression* `temp` will be converted to `char *` before being passed to `scanf`.

Second, lose the `\n` at the end of the format string - it's not necessary (`"%s"` will skip over any leading whitespace) and having it there means `fscanf` will *block* until it sees an explicit `\n` in the input stream, which could cause problems if the last line in the file isn't followed by a newline character.

Also make sure everything was read correctly:

```
if ( fscanf( time, "%s %f %d", temp, &tempp, &temps ) == 3 )
{
  // process as normal
}
or
{
  // input not formatted as expected, handle as appropriate
}
```

Comment: *"First, lose the `&` operator on `&temp` - since it's an array, the expression `temp` will be converted to `char *` before being passed to `scanf`."* -- Correct, but you may want to mention why it "just works".

Comment: Having the `"\n"` at the end does not mean it will "block until it sees an explicit `\n`". It simply means it will consume any amount (including zero) of whitespace characters (same effect as using `" "`). Or in standardese : "A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read. The directive never fails."

Comment: See [Trailing white space in a `scanf()` format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/) — the trailing white space (newline) isn't satisfied until there is something other than white space in the input.  It will read a thousand newlines if you just hit return. You have to type the start of the next input, or indicate EOF, to terminate the reading.  Yes, get rid of the newline; no, not for the reason given.